# Protractor: sendKeys doesn't work with type="number"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I'm trying to send numeric input using `sendKeys` but it isn't working. This is my HTML:

```
<input type="number" maxlength="3950">
```

And this is how I'm trying to locate the input box and add a number to it:

```
var input = element(by.css('input'));
input.clear();
browser.sleep(5000);
input.sendKeys('2'); //Here's the error
browser.sleep(1000);
var btn = element(by.css(".btn.btn-action.btn-ok" ));
```

And this is the error:

```
Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .btn.btn-action.btn-ok)
```

Comment: Please post the error you're getting.

Comment: The error message I'm getting is of no help

Answer (score 0):

First off all post the error you are getting, secondly it looks obvious that you are using a very generic selector and you may have more than one `input` on a given page. Try something unique like,

```
var input = element(by.css('input[type='number']'));
input.clear();
input.sendKeys('2');
```

Comment: Hmmm I didn't downvote you, but I fixed it nonetheless. The error log I'm getting is for the next line after the wrong line, so, it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Error would have helped point out the exact reason. I just wanted to point out something really obvious without the help of error

Comment: But how can that  be error? it's the only input on the page, besides, what you are doing in the example is wrong

Comment: All I am saying is that without you posting the error, it was difficult to identify what happened. I had no idea if you have one or more inputs, another detail missing. The error you later on added does not match the title/description of the question. Also I don't know what you see wrong in above code.  In fact the css selector in my example is much more deeper and unique than one you currently use. I hope you would use such selectors going forward. My intention was to help you. I'm glad you got it resolved some way or the other